# How to resolve Maven exec plugin: classpath too long error?

Tags: java, maven-2, classpath, maven-plugin

I have a large Java project with a large number of jar file dependencies. When I try to run the project (using exec) from Eclipse or Netbeans, Maven throws an exception which turns out to be a too large number of entries  on the classpath (only 2/3 of the needed entries are included). Does anyone know a workaround for this?  (Except from building an executable jar and running it from terminal.) Is it possbile to "extend" the "classpath-buffer"-size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Maven exec plugin bug, it is documented in [MEXEC-68](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MEXEC-68), the reporter created a patch so I hope it will be resolved soon.

One workaround would be to add the classpath to the manifest file using this config for the maven-jar-plugin, add the dependencies to a folder and add just that folder to the CLASSPATH envvar.

For example:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        ...
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        ...
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

This will add to the manifest something like:

```
Class-Path: plexus-utils-1.1.jar commons-lang-2.1.jar
```

If that JARs are in a CLASSPATH folder, you can run your JAR using maven exec plugin hidding the classpath with something like:

```
mvn exec:exec [...] -Dexec.classpathScope="test"
```

I used -Dexec.classpathScope="test" to make the plugin ignore the dependencies and add just the ones in scope test.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is fixed in Netbeans 6.10M1. Please take a look at [Bug 188864](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=188864). If you have an older version, you can still fix this yourself (you just have to edit an xml file inside org-netbeans-modules-maven.jar).

Then, don't forget to check Maven Best Practices (http://wiki.netbeans.org/MavenBestPractices#Binding_Maven_goals_to_IDE_actions) where it is explained how to bind maven goals to IDE actions.

Regards,

Mach

Answer (score 0):

In Java 6 (which I hope you use) you can use wildcards in classpath entries. For the exact syntax check this page [Setting the classpath](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) and search to the right section by searching for "`Understanding the class path and package names`".

Or you try shortening the paths by placing all required jars in a single folder with a short path. e.g. `C:\jars\`

Comment: i have already shortened the path to C:\jr\ with no luck, still to much for the exec command

Comment: Using Java 5, and it is out of my hands to upgrade it (A upgrade is requested to the customer though)